Calculate Power Spectrum From FFT
I am writing a IQ analyzer app in c++ qt and I am processing the IQ data that comes to me with fft (I am using the fftw3 library for this). Then I am trying to calculate the power spectrum. This is the code:
   fftw_complex* in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    fftw_complex* out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        in[i][0] = data[i].real();
        in[i][1] = data[i].imag();
    }

    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(plan);

    std::vector<std::complex<float>> fftResult(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        fftResult[i] = std::complex<float>(out[i][0], out[i][1]);
    }

    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);

        float result1 = sqrtf(pow(fftResult[i].real(),2) + pow(fftResult[i].imag(),2)); //
        float result2 = pow(result1,2); //
        float result3 = pow(N,2); //
        float result4 = result2 / result3; //
        float result5 = log10(result4); //
        float result6 = 10 * result5; //
        magnitude[i] = result6; //

When I show these results on the graph, the graph seems correct, but the results appear to be approximately 15 dBm higher. As the location or strength of the signal changes, the difference of 15 can increase. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

offtopic: I wonder what is rationale to use Fourier Transform on IQ data? Also why you use C library. I'm pretty sure there is C++ library for fft, which would be more handy then this.

What is Fourier Transformation normally used for? When I did research on the internet, this library was generally used. I used it in other libraries. I also tested it in Python and the results are the same. Honestly, I decided to use this library because I have more sources.

FFTW computes unnormalized sum. See 4.8.1 The 1d Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT). Side note: you can get rid of sqrt() because log(a^b) = b*log(a)

@MarekR How would you calculate spectrum of quadrature signal?

Indeed you’re probably missing the normalization. But there are lots of superfluous things you’re doing here. std::complex<float> and fftw_complex have the same layout (assuming you’re using the float version of FFTW), so you can just reinterpret_cast a pointer to your array to the pointer that FFTW wants. For result1 you compute a square root, and for result2 you immediately square it again, skip those two function calls. And having a long list of resultN variables is not exactly easy to read, if you are not going to use the intermediate results later, re-use the variable.

Is N==1024? Your additional 15 dBm look almost like 10*log(sqrt(1024)), i.e. lack of 1/N.

@CrisLuengo Thank you for your help. I wrote the resultN part for quick results, that's why it looks like that, but I'll fix it. Thanks

@dimich Actually N=2048

Ah, it makes sense. I forgot about second half of spectrum.

@dimich So if I do something like if(n==1024) n/4 else if(n==2048) n/8, how correct would the result be?

@mrhndsm To calculate exact values in dBm we have to know resolution of samples, i.e. how much mW (or mV on standard impedance) is magnitude 1.0.

If you want values just in dB scale, then fftResult[i] = 1.f / N * std::complex<float>(out[i][0], out[i][1]) and calculate magnitude as 10 * logf(fftResult[i].real() * fftResult[i].real() + fftResult[i].imag() * fftResult[i].imag()) (or 20 * logf(hypotf(fftResult[i].real(), fftResult[i].imag())), it is the same)

@dimich std::complex has an overload for abs() that returns the magnitude. No need to write it out in full. Though as you pointed out earlier, you can get rid of the sqrt overhead by using the log identity (which would require some manual work).

@SirNate Thanks. Indeed, 20 * logf(abs(fftResult[i])) is even simpler. I'm just used to use fftw in C.

@dimich Thank you for answers but i did not understand clearly, i am sorry for that. fftResult[i] = 1.f / N * std::complex(out[i][0], out[i][1]); After doing this process, I perform normalization operations. float result1 = fftResult[i].real() * fftResult[i].real() + fftResult[i].imag() * fftResult[i].imag(); float result2 = result1; float result3 = pow(N,2); float result4 = result2 / result3; float result5 = log10(abs(result4)); float result6 = 10 * result5; magnitude[i] = result6;  the result is very different then. Not the same as first result.

@mrhndsm I don't understand why so many intermediate results. Assuming I/Q samples are levels, to calculate power at some frequency in dB scale you need MdB=20*log(M) where M is modulus (magnitude). M=sqrt(re²+im²) or in terms of C++ M=std::abs(fftResult[i]). If you fill your input data with unit frequency cos(ωt)+i*sin(ωt) you'll have 0 dB at 1st harmonic (reference power level) and big negative values at other frequencies (no power).

You can "optimize" calculation by moving out sqrt from log, i.e. P=20*log(sqrt(re²+im²))=20*1/2*log(re²+im²)=10*log(re²+im²), i.e. 20 becomes 10. You can also move normalization 1/N out of log, i.e. don't normalize fftResult[i] but substract 20*log(N) from the result. It looks more like math/engineering problem, not a programming.

If you already have done normalization with fftResult[i] = 1.f / N * ..., you don't need to float result3 = pow(N,2); float result4 = result2 / result3, and vice versa.

Also you already calculated sum of squares in result1 = fftResult[i].real() * fftResult[i].real() + fftResult[i].imag() * fftResult[i].imag(), so you don't need abs(result4) for result5 in this case.

@dimich Thank you for everything and i am so sorry and i apologize about understandability of code and myself.

Of course, all log()s are base-10 above.

Don't apologize, asking questions is first step to get answers. The issue seems to be in math, and from there it got into the code. Try to write down math first. Also test code using some reference signals which spectrum is well known.
